# Bottom Bar for NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a bottom bar for a navigation controller? If so, how does one set it up?

I would like to have a global bottom bar without having to add it to every view.

Is it possible to use a toolbar and add it to the navigation controller, so that each view will not need to have the same bar added?

Comment: Have you seen such a design in some app to help imagine the view?

Comment: Do you mean `UIToolbar` or `UITabBar`?

Comment: UIToolbar probably. Is it handled by UIKit that it is visible on every pushed view controller, but remains a single instance? I would like to add controls to it, and not have to create a UIViewController and add it to each view I want it in.

Comment: Is it really necessary to ask this? Just a glance at the UINavigationController docs answer it.

Answer (score 3):

If your `UINavigationController` is instantiated in the `AppDelegate`, you can call

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]
```

To add items to your toolbar from a ViewController

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarItems:items animated:NO];
```

whereby items is an array of `UIBarButtonItem`s

Comment: Great. Can I add controls to it from any ViewController like with the navigation controller? self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem for example.

Comment: Yes, by calling [self setToolbarItems:(NSArray*) animated:(BOOL)]